# Dash double semicolon (;;) syntax

Tags: syntax, sh, dash-shell

I'm trying to find a way to run multiple commands in parallel in `sh` and wait for it completion.

I've found that following doesn't work (`sh: 1: Syntax error: ";" unexpected`):

```
sh -c '(sleep 3 && echo 1) & ; (sleep 3 && echo 2) & ;  wait'
```

But this syntax works as expected:

```
sh -c '(sleep 3 && echo 1) & ;; (sleep 3 && echo 2) & ;;  wait'
```

But I don't understand what is the difference.

What is the meaning of `;;` and when it should be used?

Comment: neither command line worked here. `;;` is option separator for `case` statement.

Comment: sorry, i was wrong, it actually gives error in bash, but works in dash

Answer (score 103, accepted):

`;;` is only used in `case` constructs, to indicate the end of an alternative. (It's present where you have `break` in C.)

```
case $answer in
  yes) echo 'yay!';;
  no) echo 'boo!';;
esac
```

Syntactically, `;` and `&` both mark the end of a command. A newline is equivalent to `;`, in a first approximation. The difference between them is that `;` or newline indicates that the command must be executed in the foreground, whereas `&` indicates that the command must be executed in the background.

So here you need `& wait`. `& ;` is a syntax error (you can't have an empty command). `& ;;` is also a syntax error; ash lets it go (as if you'd written just `&`), but bash complains. Evidently your sh is some ash variant (such as dash, which is `/bin/sh` on many Debian derivatives).

Comment: Quoting the important bit: Syntactically, `;` and `&` both mark the end of a command. So here you need `& wait`.

Answer (score 9):

It should be used in a `case` statement, between cases. The issue you're having here is that both `&` and `;` are command separators, and you should only be using one of them.

Comment: Thank you for clarification, `sh -c '(sleep 3 && echo 1) & (sleep 3 && echo 2) & wait'` is working as expected. It doesn't explains though what is meaning `;;` in this context.

Comment: Are you sure that `sh` is `bash`?

Comment: Sorry, I was wrong, it isn't bash, it [dash](http://gondor.apana.org.au/~herbert/dash/)